# protractor timeout after 30000msec

Tags: windows, selenium-webdriver, jasmine, nant, protractor

I am tryin to integrate protractor e2e tests in my cruisecontrol I am using the following testspec:

```
describe('index', function () {
    var ptor;

    it('should have a title', function () {
        browser.get('http://juliemr.github.io/protractor-demo/');

        expect(browser.getTitle()).toEqual('Super Calculator');
    });

    it('Check google', function () {
        browser.driver.get('http://www.google.com');
    })
});
```

When I run this spec though the command line  works fine. However when I run it as a nant target in the build config it says there is a timeout error:

```
31mtimeout: timed out after 30000 msec waiting for spec to complete
```

How can I get my protractor e2e tests goin though the cc.net ?

Comment: Did you manage to fix it? Have similar issue with teamcity. Dont think its about the timeout.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to set time out interval, for example: `jasmineNodeOpts: {defaultTimeoutInterval: 500000}` more info [here](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/timeouts)

Comment: How can it fix the issue? 30 seconds should be enough to load the page. I have the same issue, browser.driver.get just hangs.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding below timeoutinterval in config file

```
jasmineNodeOpts: {
defaultTimeoutInterval: 360000
}
allScriptsTimeout: 360000,
```

You can modify the miliseconds of timeout