# Keep browser alive using protractor

Tags: jasmine, protractor

I'm using protractor to run an E2E tests using Jasmine, my problem is that the URL I gave to it needs a long time to load (authenticate and login), but the protractor browser is being killed (closed) before the page is loaded, how could I keep the browser running till the page is loaded?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you should increase timeout? [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26450182/protractor-timeout-after-30000msec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26450182/protractor-timeout-after-30000msec)

Comment: it didn't work to me still closing the page after some seconds

Answer (score 0):

When navigating to a new page using browser.get, Protractor waits for the page to be loaded and the new URL to appear before continuing.

**Error** - Error: Timed out waiting for page to load after 10000ms

Default timeout: 10 seconds

**How to change:** To change globally, add **getPageTimeout: timeout_in_millis** to your Protractor configuration file. For an individual call to get, pass an additional parameter: browser.get(address, timeout_in_millis)

Code:
     config.js file:

```
 { 
  //statements
  ........
   getPageTimeout:120000//120 seconds
  ....................
 }
```

Comment: when I add the page timeout it closed get quicker

Comment: try with different time values like 3 min etc